# Hungerford Chapter 4 Section 5 Problem 7

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products, tensors

The usual injection $\alpha : Z_2\rightarrow Z_4$ is a monomorphism of abelian groups. Show that $1\otimes \alpha :Z_2\otimes Z_2 \rightarrow Z_2\otimes Z_4$ is the zero map.

---

My solution :
According to me the usual injection betwwen $Z_2$ and $Z_4$ is given by $\alpha (x)=2x$ then $1\otimes \alpha (0\otimes 0)=0\otimes 0=0$

$1\otimes \alpha (1\otimes 1)=1\otimes 2$

$1\otimes \alpha (1\otimes 0)=1\otimes 0=0$

$1\otimes \alpha (0\otimes 1)=0\otimes 2=0$

---

then yes $1\otimes \alpha$ is not one to one, but where i m wrong because the question is saying to prove it a zero map?

Answer (score 1):

If $x\otimes 2$ is a simple tensor in $\mathbb{Z}_2\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Z}_4$, then $x\otimes 2=x\otimes 2\cdot 1=2x\otimes 1=0\otimes 1=0$.

Comment: ok thanks for the help